# Iterate an array reference and convert to hash in perl

Tags: perl

I have an hash (Printed by Dumper) which is described below

```
$VAR1 = {
          'items' => [
                    {
                      'name' => 'test1',
                      'id' => '1',
                      'desc' => 'desc1',
                    },
                    {
                      'name' => 'test2',
                      'id' => '2',
                      'desc' => 'desc2',
                    }
                  ],
           };
```

I need to convert "items" which is array reference to a hash like below. ('items' will be a hash of hash with the value of 'id' being the key)

```
$VAR1 = {
          'items' => {
                     '1' =>{
                         'name' => 'test1',
                         'id' => '1',
                         'desc' => 'desc1',
                      },
                     '2' => {
                         'name' => 'test2',
                         'id' => '2',
                         'desc' => 'desc2',
                    }
                  }
           };
```

Lets start with the below code. (Assume $data represents the original data and $newitems represents the modified items)

```
my $data;
my $items = $data->{items};
my %newitems;
foreach my $element (@$items) {
......
}
```

Comment: Is this parsed XML? It looks like the kind of junk data structure you get from `XML::Simple`. If so, I'd suggest the answer is 'go upstream' and use something else to parse your XML. If that's not the case, i'd suggest maybe actually try and do it, and see where you get stuck.

Comment: as @Sobrique says, if its so you'll need to use other module, cause XML::Simple is really discouraged to use by its own respective owners, if its generated by others things, please describe how you get your hash

Comment: Thanks. Yes its a parsed XML by XML::Twig. (Actually XML::Simple produces the right data for me). I got the hash using the below code. my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
$twig->parsefile("xyz.xml");
my  $data = $twig->simplify(forcearray => ["items"], keyattr => [ "id"]);

Comment: You're spitting out the structure using `simplify` then? You can use the same parameters as `XML::Simple`. But honestly - you shouldn't. Just iterate the elements in in the twig data structure, and do your transformation there. I can't give you an example of what this would look like, without your source and target XML though. But it's almost certainly easier than you think.

Comment: Yah. I used the same parameters as XML::Simple. But its not working. That is the reason I want to iterate over the array reference and covert to the format I need. But I am new to perl. Not been able to get it working. I wrote a skeleton code at the end. Would appreciate if anyone can help me out. Sorry If its very simple.

Comment: Hi Sobrique. Please disregard my previous comment. Your answer works. Thanks

Comment: OK. I'll point out that by exporting your XML and mangling a data structure, you're almost certainly doing something in in a brittle and suboptimal way. You can usually 'just' walk the XML, using `xpath` to select things you want in the way you want them instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an XY problem to me - I'm guessing you're trying to transform some XML, so I'd suggest you want to look upstream to solve this problem.

But on the offchance you're not, then:

```
$data -> {items} = { map { $_ -> {id} => $_ } @{$data->{items} } };
```